# Tomar valores de fichero.txt

Tags: c

Buenas, tengo una pequeña duda. Debo cargar unos datos de un fichero de txt
con tres columnas, la primera no es necesaria que la guarde.

El tamaño de los vectores a de ser de 15000 muestras, ¿debo hacer la longitud de estos como vectores dinámicos?

Adjunto la parte del código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MUESTRA 15000


FILE *fd,*fl;
char c,d;


int main(){


    int L, N, H, M; // longitud, pnts vecinos, umbral, nº pulsos encoder
    int i,j,c,*intensidad,*contaje,cont=0;
    intensidad = (int*)malloc(MUESTRA*sizeof(int));
    contaje = (int*)malloc(MUESTRA*sizeof(int));
    char aux;
    char temp[20];
    char direccion [] ="C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Trabajo Programacion\\Senyales trabajo 1\\configuracion.txt";
    char direccion2 [] ="C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Trabajo Programacion\\Senyales trabajo 1\\senyal1.txt";
    fd = fopen(direccion,"r");
    fl = fopen(direccion2,"r");

    if(fd == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }

    if(fl == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fd, "%d", &L);
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &N);
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &H);
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &M);


    for (i=0; i<MUESTRA; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fl, "%d", *(intensidad+i));
        fscanf(fl, "%d", *(contaje+i));

        printf("%d\n",*(intensidad+i));
        printf("%d\n",*(contaje+i));

    }

    intensidad = (int*)realloc(intensidad,MUESTRA*sizeof(int));
    contaje = (int*)realloc(contaje,MUESTRA*sizeof(int));

    printf("%d \n",L);
    printf("%d\n",N);
    printf("%d\n",H);
    printf("%d\n",M);

    fclose(fd);
    fclose(fl);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dado el tamaño, 15000 elementos, lo adecuado es hacerlos en el *heap*; da igual hacerlos dinámicos o estáticos. ¿ Esa es toda la pregunta ?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta